# Unit test form submission not triggered by button outside of form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, testing, react-testing-library

I'm trying to unit test with React Testing Library a form submission function, however my button to submit the form is outside of the form itself, but is linked via the `form=...` attribute.

Here is an example test that is failing:

```
it('my test', () => {
    const formSubmit = jest.fn(() => console.log('/// Form submitted ///'));

    render(<div>
        <form id="test-form" onSubmit={formSubmit}>
            <button type="submit">Inside form</button>
        </form>
        <button form="test-form" type="submit">Outside form</button>
    </div>);

    // Running this line DOES print the console log correctly
    // userEvent.click(screen.getByText('Inside form'));

    // This line DOES NOT print the console log...
    userEvent.click(screen.getByText('Outside form'));

    // Clicking the outside button means this also fails.
    expect(formSubmit).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Is there something I am missing here?

---

**Update**

After a lot of Googling it seems that this issue was caused by me using an older version of JEST for my testing.

It was noted on [this](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/755) GIT issue that there was an issue with older versions of JSDOM that caused this.

> This particular issue is likely caused by using older jsdom
> environments (via jest). The bug was fixed in jsdom/jsdom#2369 which
> was released in jsdom@12.2.0

It looks like I was using "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.12.0" but upgrading to the latest ^5.16.2 **doesn't** seem to have fixed the issue.

Comment: The test seem to pass for me. `/// Form submitted ///` is getting logged on the code provided.

Comment: @NeERAJTK what versions of Jest/JSDom are you using? See my update on the original question for mine

Comment: `"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1"`

Comment: @NeERAJTK hmm something else must be wrong then... Like I said, `5.16.2` doesn't seem to solve the issue for me. Running `jest --version` is bringing back `24.9.0` which is a version that won't work. I wonder how I can update this...

Comment: Have you tried installing `jest-environment-jsdom-fifteen`? `npm install --save-dev jest-environment-jsdom-fifteen`

Comment: @NeERAJTK looks like I've had `-fourteen` as a dependency in most things according to my `package-lock` file. Updating to `-fifteen` as you suggested has thrown a few issues when doing `npm i` so I will try resolving them and report back.

Comment: Okay. [Update it in jest.config file also](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/setup#jest-24-or-lower-and-defaults)

Comment: @NeERAJTK thank God you were here to help! It wasn't a smooth process with many runs of `npm i`, but we eventually got there! Thanks for the pointers.

Comment: Glad it helped :)